# Error al iniciar sesión SQL Server al reiniciar PC

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi problema es que después de apagar y prender el PC y entrar a mi portal me sale el mensaje de **error establishing a database connection** y me fijo que no hay conexión a SQL Server, entonces inicio sesion con Autenticación de SQL Server  con el usuario (sa) y clave configurados durante la instalación y sale este mensaje.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba seguro de que ingresaba los datos correctamente al iniciar sesión pero no me conectaba, entonces lo que hice fue conectarme con modo autenticación con windows y cambiar la clave a la que tenia, luego cambio el modo de autenticacion y logro conectar.

Habra una forma de corregir este problema sin tener que cambiar clave cada vez que prendo la PC y tener que reinstalar el SQL Server. Estaba corriendo con normalidad, los servicios de SQL y  IIS están corriendo automáticamente pero hace un par de días me sale este problema:

- SQL Server 2014 express adv.
- Windows 10
- IIS 10
- Wordpress (con project nami)

Answer (score 1):

Este error nace de que los servicios de sql server no se activan al momento de que se instalan para poder corregir esto lo podemos hacer de forma manual para que se activen mientras estamos usando el equipo y si no deseamos repetir esta acción lo podemos colocar en automático para que se active cada que encienda el equipo y esto lo hacemos de la siguiente forma:
NT: El resultado del numero del error varia de acuerdo a las versiones pero esto se resuelve de la misma forma.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0ytg_pqgho

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tu servidor no tiene habilitadas las conexiones remotas.

Revisa la configuración del servidor con  el administrador de configuración de SQL Server.

SUERTE

Comment: he configurado para habilitar las conexiones remotas, inlcuso TCP/IP  guiándome de algunas paginas y el problema todavía persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que:

1. Abrir tu buscador de Windows y buscar: herramientas de configuración de SQL Server.
2. Aparece un menú del lado izquierdo que dice "servicios SQL Server"
3. Le das click y después
4. Le das click derecho al servicio que quieras levantar (iniciar)

y listo!